# WiFi Only works for short time

Tags: wireless, internet, madwifi

I have dell Inspiron 15N Notebook, and installed Ubuntu 15.04 with gnome. My WiFi is properly detected and connected at the beginning and it works fine, but after 4-5 minutes the internet connection is lost even if the wifi is connected. I have to finally connect it to LAN cable after restarting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem with my dell XPS. I had to call tech support. It turn out I had to open my laptop, unplug-replug the WiFi antenna.

It should look like this: http://eduncan911.com/blog/archives/images/WhytheInspironisaKing_13F13/IMG_0008.jpg